# "Mean pooled difference" or "pooled mean difference"?

Tags: meta-analysis

Perhaps this is purely semantics but meta-analyses use these in interchangeably but which is more legitimate or are neither because there should be a hyphen?

I would say pooled mean difference because you're pooling the mean difference. I wouldn't use a hyphen because the "mean difference" is being pooled, not just the "mean".

*No this question doesn't belong in English literature or semantics because it's a statistical term and sense of it must be made from a statistical standpoint*

Comment: I'd go with "polled mean difference", as in "pooled covariance". It's describing something( the mean) as pooled.

Answer (score 1):

*Mean difference* is just a type of effect size. We also have *median difference*, *Cohen's d* and *Hedges' g* which are *standardized mean difference*, etc. In meta-analysis, these effect sizes are *pooled*, *weighted*, or *averaged* then you get things like *pooled mean difference*.